# Wordpress site - home page opens but inner pages give 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

This seems like very trivial, that its a .htaccess file issue, but it isn't.

I have a wordpress site, which was running at say demo.xxx.com I had to move it to xxx.com
so i just went to my apache and change the files to redirect the same to xxx.com and not to demo.xxx.com

i also went in wordpress and changed the url related settings from demo.xxx.com to xxx.com
the directory thus is the same for this source code.
the home page opens well, at first i thought may be i should reset all the permalinks, which i did but the inner pages refuse to open.

my .htaccess file is same as before, I don;t think there is anything wrong about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to go to Settings -> Permalinks and choose a setting different from Default, then click the Save button?

Comment: let me try that too btw i see this error in my logs at apache [Tue Aug 26 17:23:54 2014] [error] [client 115.252.160.145] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/demoXXX/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 622, referer: http://theXXX.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?activate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=

Comment: hmmm ... interesting changed it to default it worked, but when changed back to previous setting stopped working again, I do really need URL's like http://example.com/about-us

Comment: If only the default URLs are working then most possibly the apache mod rewrite is not enabled. So in case you can't enable it, you should stick with the default URLs.

Comment: well if it wasn't how come the demo.xx was working on the same server with the same type of URL's , it just seems logically impossible

Comment: This means that this is related either with some custom code in your theme, or with plugins that are breaking the rewrite rule generation or the .htaccess generation. So you can try disabling the plugins one by one, as well as check your theme code for errors.

Comment: yes looks like, thanks anyways for helping me to run it at least :)

Answer (score 0):

When you directed Apache to go to your new site, was it in a different directory? If so, you probably don't have the same directory permissions. Permalinks use mod_rewrite and won't work unless Overrides are enabled.

Check and change your httpd.conf file...

```
<Directory "/var/www/xxx.dom">
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "/var/www/xxx.dom">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: baa it was the same file i just changed the hostname, and it worked, I am new to Wordpress so didm;t wanted to go through entire migration pain, but nonetheless it was supposed to happen with me :)